# Connection Reset Tomcat8 Webapp after 10 minutes

Tags: java, tomcat, httpconnection, connection-reset

trying to make a post with XML payload from my java webapp to another Tomcat Server I get "Connection Reset" if and only if the request takes more than 10 minutes (600000 ms)

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140) ~[okio-1.14.0.jar:?]
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237) ~[okio-1.14.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:355) ~[okio-1.14.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227) ~[okio-1.14.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.burgstaller.okhttp.AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.java:45) ~[okhttp-digest-1.17.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77) ~[okhttp-3.10.0.jar:?]
```

I tried to make the same request with curl from the same VM, where the webapp runs and it works even if the the request take 20 minutes. Also I tried to do this from my local machine and it works also. 
The tomcat server needs sometimes 10 or more minutes to handle the request.

I suggest there is some kind of default value, which breaks the connection after 10 minutes.

I tried also to set SO_KEEPALIVE and to use another http client e.g. Jersy, but it doesn't help.

Do you have any Ides, what can it be?

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy in front of your Tomcat server?  The timeout could be happening there.

Comment: No, I don't also tried curl from the same VM with the same request und it works.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a problem in the network (outside of Java).   The fact that you don't get the problem from within the VM is particularly revealing.